# Error installing XML packege in R (libxml2)

Tags: r, terminal, package, mlr3

I am trying to install the `mlr3` library in R. THe `XML` library (one of the dependencies) gives me problems since it returns the following error:

```
You are trying to use a version 2.* edition of libxml
but an incompatible library. The header files and library seem to be
mismatched. If you have specified LIBXML_INCDIR, make certain to also
specify an appropriate LIBXML_LIBDIR if the libxml2 library is not in the default
directories.
```

I already tried to uninstall and re-install (via brew) libxml2 but nothing changes.
What should I try?

I am working in RStudio on a MacBook with Catalina installed.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by running the following,

> devtools::install_github("r-lib/xml2")